# not getting QR code after fresh installtion for magento 2.4

Tags: magento2.4

I've installed magneto 2.4 and enabled 2fa following the instructions in this link
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/deployment/pipeline/example/cli.html

I don't understand what I should be doing on the third step: magento/tfa/OTP_SHARED_SECRET=

and after logging in using admin account I don't get QR code to scan.
am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way, by adding a system configuration to Enable/Disable it. I made a module, you can download it with composer:

```
composer require wolfsellers/module-enabledisabletfa
```

Or check it at: https://github.com/wolfsellers/module-enabledisabletfa